# Regression loop: several dep variables & several indep variables, one of these indep variables takes different values according to the dep variable

Tags: r, loops, regression

I have several dependent variables (let's call them dep1, dep2 and dep3) and I want to regress several independent variables on them. I have the independent variables a,b and c which I always want to include in the regression. However the independent variables d1, d2, d3 should only be used when the number matches the number of the dependent variable. This is:

```
lm(dep1 ~ a + b + c + d1)
lm(dep2 ~ a + b + c + d2)
lm(dep3 ~ a + b + c + d3)
```

To be more exact, both my dependent and independent variables are a monthly time series (xts object). I merged the dependent variables to get the matrix "dep". a,b,c,d1,d2 and d3 are stored in the matrix "indep".

Is it possible to create a loop which does this automatically?

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example.  Do you have a `data.frame` or are these all vector objects

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: You could put `d1-d3` in a list, iterate through `lm(...,d[[i]])` for `i in 1:3`, and save the results in another list called `dep`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you be more specific? I am new to r and do not know how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

We can use `paste`

```
v1 <- paste0("dep", 1:3)
v2 <- paste0("d", 1:3)
v3 <- paste(v1, paste(paste(letters[1:3], collapse=" + "), v2, sep=" + "), sep="~")
lapply(v3, function(x) lm(x))
```

Comment: Thank you! But in this example, where did I specify the independent variables and what is x? I am sorry, I am quite new to R...

Comment: I tried to implement it but I get the folling error message: "variable dep1 not found"...

Comment: @Lila Please provide a reproducible example.  It is based on your description